# How to compile trivial files to PostgreSQL source?

Tags: database, postgresql, database-design

I have some ideas for modifications to PostgreSQL, so I have set up a suitable development environment on Windows. Now I am playing around to understand how to contribute new code to it.

I have copied some files from the backend and renamed them: the goal is to compile the old code with the new code so that PostgreSQL can recognise this. I suppose another alternative would be to create a copy of the system and compile both, one with a modification and one without, so I can compare both side by side but I am not sure how to configure pgAdmin to recognise between both. To provide some more details, I am working on PostgreSQL's indexes at the backend folder.

I thought these would be very simple things to do but I am having so much trouble. How can I achieve this task? Any related material would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If I read this correctly, you've modified some of the source code in `src/backend` and wish to apply your modifications to an existing PostgreSQL install.

You can't do that. You need to compile a new PostgreSQL binary (`postgres.exe`) with the source code including the modifications. Then install the new PostgreSQL distribution you compiled. For instructions on compiling for windows see [the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/install-windows-full.html). Note that *not all Visual Studio and Visual Studio Express versions are supported by all PostgreSQL releases* so use a Visual Studio that's supported by the PostgreSQL you are compiling. You may also need to compile and/or download some library dependencies depending on the feature set you require - zlib for example. (This is all much easier on Linux, it's only Windows builds that're a bit annoying).

If your modified source is of the same major version (e.g 9.4 or 9.6) as the currently running PostgreSQL install you can then stop the currently running install and start your modified binaries. But *only* if you changed nothing relating to the on-disk format, since otherwise the new binaries won't be compatible with the old format of the data. Obviously you should also take a backup before running experimental PostgreSQL builds on your data!

See also:

- https://www.postgresql.org/developer/
- https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/So,_you_want_to_be_a_developer%3F
- https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Developer_FAQ
- https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/internals.html